# Invalid XAML but work when running

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have this XAML for my ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LbBatidas" ItemsSource="{Binding Batidas}" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="72">
                <Image Source="{Binding Natureza, Converter={StaticResource NaturezaBatidaConverter}}" Width="72"/>                                 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Horario, StringFormat=\{0:HH:mm:ss\}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

But when I run my application its completly normal.

If I remove converters of Image source binding the erro of Invalid XAML stop

```
<ListBox x:Name="LbBatidas" ItemsSource="{Binding Batidas}" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="72">
                <Image Source="{Binding Natureza}" Width="72"/>                                 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Horario, StringFormat=\{0:HH:mm:ss\}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

[image: Invalid XAML Error]

Link of source code: 
https://projects.developer.nokia.com/MeuPonto

Comment: Aaaaaand the error is.... what?

Comment: "Invalid XAML" is the Error.

Comment: Check your console messages.  And I'd bet your converter is throwing an exception.

Comment: Will, that is the console message, I will take screenshot and show here.

Comment: Try this as well--in your converter, at the start of Convert and ConvertBack, add `if(System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())) return value;`  This will short-circuit whatever logic is inside during design time and may fix the error.

Comment: Will I added link of source code and image of error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Convert and ConvertBack methods like this:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var v = value as NaturezaBatida;
        if (v == null)
            return null;

        var imageSource = v == NaturezaBatida.Entrada
                              ? new Uri("/Imagens/Entrada.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                              : new Uri("/Imagens/Saida.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        return new BitmapImage(imageSource);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

You should return null or an empty/default image in your Convert method instead of the passed in object.

Comment: I stoped to try discover the error, and rewrite application UI, didnt touched in converter, it was working fine.

Comment: Could you please post your new UI code, so others can see how you fixed the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I will publish the link for project in Nokia Git, and I will specify the commit that was with this problem.

Answer (score -2):

simple just rebuild your solution.
click on Build -> Rebuild sloution